# jQUERY drop down wont, close when i click it, unless i have a # in my anchor tag.it stays dropped down,nothing happens when i click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, javascript-framework

sorry i do want tag to link to login.

### only the register and login page is suppose to drop down. the register code is the same. this is the html code for the page

```
    <header id ="logo_nav"> 

   <img class="logo" src="logo.png" width=" 382"  height="122 " alt="voucher">

     <ul id= "main_nav">
     <li> <a href="index.php"> Home   </a></li>



<li id ="login">
   <a id="login-trigger" href="login.php">
 Login here  <span> ▼ </span>
    </a>  

   <div id="login-content"> 

  <form action = "log.php" method="post">


    <label id="user"> Username  </label>

   <br/>
<input id="inputbox"type="text" name="username"> 

   <br/>
<label id="pass"> Password  </label> 

    <br/>

<input  id="pinput" type="password" name="password">  <br/>




 <input id="submit" type="submit" value ="log in">
     </form>
```

- Below is the jquery code thats not allowing me to drop down and
  close.

  ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
  ```

  $('#login-trigger').click(function(){
      $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
      $(this).toggleClass('active');

  ```
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
      else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
  })
        });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `href="#"`, since you don't want  tag to link anywhere.

Comment: sorry i do want tag to link to login.php

Comment: But this way click will cause user to go to `login.php` which (I guess) is not what you want

Comment: i dont understand? i want the drop down to expand and close when i click it, it must link to login.php when  clicked as this website is suppose to give the illusion its a one page website